# Как определить переменную типа int в Пайтоне?

Tags: python

```
import math

x = input('Введите х: ')
y = input('Введите у: ')
z = input('Введите z: ')
a = input('Введите a: ')
b = input('Введите b: ')
c = input('Введите c: ')
d = input('Введите d: ')
f = input('Введите f: ')

result = (math.cos(x)**2/math.sin(x))
```

Ввожу числа, а ошибку выбивает такую:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Владислав\Desktop\Lab 1\lab1.py", line 17, in <module>
    result = (math.cos(x)**2/math.sin(x))
TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

Comment: Так: `int(input())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот ваш код с выводом результата:

```
import math

x = int(input('Введите х: '))
y = int(input('Введите у: '))
z = int(input('Введите z: '))
a = int(input('Введите a: '))
b = int(input('Введите b: '))
c = int(input('Введите c: '))
d = int(input('Введите d: '))
f = int(input('Введите f: '))

result = (math.cos(x)**2/math.sin(x))
print(result)
```

Результат:

```
Введите х: 1
Введите у: 1
Введите z: 1
Введите a: 1
Введите b: 1
Введите c: 1
Введите d: 1
Введите f: 1
0.3469241209702246
```